# NER Tools for academic use

Tags: python

I have some research project which needs best NER results .
Can anyone please help me with the best NER tools which have a Python library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about Java, [Stanford NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) seems to be the best ceteris paribus.
There is also [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/ne/read-me.html), [Illinois](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/4) and others, take a look at [ACL list](http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Named_entity_recognizers).

Also consider [this paper](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1308/1308.0661.pdf) for experimental comparison of several NERCs.